# Object Detection in AWS + Sagemaker Neo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying the inbuilt object detection algorithm available on AWS for a computer vision problem. The training job ran successfully and I have received the model artifacts in the .tar.gz format in an S3 bucket.

To reduce the model footprint, we need to use Sagemaker Neo - a compilation job on the available model artifacts. The compilation job fails with the error - "ClientError: OperatorNotImplemented:('One or more operators are not supported in frontend MXNet:\n_contrib_MultiBoxTarget: 1\nMakeLoss: 3"

How can this be resolved?
Around August 2019, Sagemaker Neo did not support models trained with built-in Sagemaker Object Detection Algorithm. Is there any change in this status today ?

Thanks